# SQL removing data from an array depending on field value

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

I'm still quite new to this and have come across a problem I have been looking through a lot of tutorials and cannot figure a way to get over the problem.

I have a select query getting data out of my sql database however I need the data to be custom for each user who accesses it, so need to add a further query, I have a cookie read in with the user value '$user' and there is a collumn in the database that isnt put into the table however need to check that if the collumn 'privacy' has a value set as '1' and the $user is not the investigator of that row discard and do not put into the table. however populate with all data that isn't set to privacy='1' or is set to privacy=1 and the investigator='$user'

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM evidence WHERE $evidencevariable = '".$evidencespecify."'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if($result === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error());}

echo "<table class='sortable' border='1' id='table'>
<thead><tr>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Case Id</th>
<th>Investigator</th>
<th>Evidence Type</th>
<th>Created</th>
<th>Modified</th>
<th>LS</th>
<th>PS</th>
<th>Length</th>
<th>Importance</th>
<th>Information</th>
</tr></thead><tbody>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Id'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Case_ID'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Investigator'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Evidence_Type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Created'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Modified'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['LS'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['PS'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Length'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Importance'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Information'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

How can I get around this problem do I need to add more to the select statement at the beginning or is there a way of querying the array to remove the data before its put into  the table?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you can easily modify the sql to something like:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE $evidencevariable='$evidencespecifiy' AND (Privacy=0 or (Privacy=1 AND investigator='$user'))";
```

Comment: Sorry it wasn't the best explanation of the problem:

SO I NEED TO SELECT * WHERE $EVIDENCE VARIABLE = $EVIDENCE SPECIFY
AND ONLY SHOW THAT DATA IF (Privacy = 0 or Privacy = 1 investigator = $user)

SHOW RESULTS .. I hope that explains it a bit better!!!

Comment: SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE $evidencevariable=$evidencespecifiy

AND ONLY SELECT THAT DATA IF

`Privacy`=0 OR (`Privacy`=1 AND `Investigator`=$user)

DISPLAY DATA

Comment: I modified the query and updated my answer based on your comments.

Comment: Perfect Bubba!! did a couple little tweaks and got it working thank you so much for your assistance!!